# Enternal Data Refresh - Preparing Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that was saved with only minor- manually entered updates. The issue is the external data connection on another sheet was somehow impacted. It used to go from reading source data to calculating when the refresh button was clicked. Now it goes from reading source data to preparing worksheet where it lingers. The difference in function changes it from a <20 second refresh to a 5+ min refresh. Any ideas on how to restore its original functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was not an excel issue. The sharepoint connection was just slow at points. A few days later, without any updates, the file worked again.